# Find the solution y for $2xdy-2ydx=\sqrt{x^2+4y^2}dx$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$2xdy-2ydx=\sqrt{x^2+4y^2}dx$$

$$2xdy-2ydx=\sqrt{x^2+4y^2}dx\Rightarrow 2x\frac{dy}{dx}-2y=\sqrt{x^2+4y^2}\Rightarrow 2\frac{dy}{dx}-2\frac{y}{x}=\sqrt{1+4(\frac{y}{x})^2}$$

$z=\frac{y}{x}\Rightarrow y=zx\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dz}{dx}x+z$

$$2(\frac{dz}{dx}x+z)-2z=\sqrt{1+4z^2}\Rightarrow 2x\frac{dz}{dx}=\sqrt{1+4z^2}\Rightarrow \frac{2x}{dx}=\frac{\sqrt{1+4z^2}}{dz}\Rightarrow \frac{dx}{2x}=\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1+4z^2}}$$

Integration on both parts:

$$\frac{1}{2}ln(2x)=ln(1+\sqrt{1+4z^2})+c\Rightarrow \sqrt{2x}=1+\sqrt{1+4z^2}e^c\Rightarrow z=-+\sqrt{\frac{2x-1}{4e^c}-\frac{1}{4}}$$

So

$$y=-+x\sqrt{\frac{2x-1}{4e^c}-\frac{1}{4}}$$

But the answer on [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2xdy-2ydx%3Dsqrt(x%5E2%2B4y%5E2)dx) is : $y=\frac{1}{2}x\sinh(c+\log x)$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the integral of $\dfrac{dz}{\sqrt{1+4z^2}}$ is not correct.

We should have $\frac{1}{2}\sinh^{-1}(2z)+C$ instead.

Solving through should lead to $y=\frac{1}{2}x \sinh(\ln(2x)+C)$